# jstl forEach not printing array elements on different lines

Tags: html, arrays, jsp, for-loop, jstl

on a .jsp page I am trying to iterate through an array and print each out on a new line. It currently works however each element of the array is printed on the same line. I have tried both of the following two methods and neither work:

```
 <c:forEach var="individualPath" items="${paths}">
    <tr>
        <td>${individualPath}<br></td>
    </tr>
    <br>
</c:forEach>
```

and

```
<c:forEach var="individualPath" items="${paths}">
<c:out value="${individualPath}" />
    <p>
</c:forEach>
```

have also tried using java/jsp to do it instead of jstl as follows:

```
<c:forEach var="individualPath" items="${paths}">
    <c:out value="${individualPath}" />
    <%
        out.print("\n");
    %>
</c:forEach>
```

have also tried using the `<pre></pre>` tags to preserve whitespace with the same erroneous outcome: both of my paths condensed onto a single line

```
`<pre><c:forEach var="path" items="${paths}">${path}<br/></c:forEach></pre>`
```

help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The break tag should work but you have them all inside <td> and <tr> tags. That makes them all on same row(at least in the first code block).

Comment: I was wrong. Prince Mani Gupta is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried but in my case,it is working as expected.Lets have a look at code

```
<table border="1">
      <h3>From 1 to 10</h3>
      <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="10">
        <tr>
        <td>${i}<br></td>
        </tr>
      </c:forEach>
</table>
```

I looked into the source of page which is also as per expectation.

```
<table border="1">
          <h3>From 1 to 10</h3>

            <tr>
            <td>1<br></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>2<br></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>3<br></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>4<br></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>5<br></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>6<br></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>7<br></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>8<br></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>9<br></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>10<br></td>
            </tr>

    </table>
```

Check the source how it is getting converted and share with us.May be that can give a pointer to start.